# Java not found package

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, java

In my project there are import:

```
import static com.sun.java.accessibility.util.AWTEventMonitor.addKeyListener;
```

but javac say:

```
error: package com.sun.java.accessibility.util does not exist
import static com.sun.java.accessibility.util.AWTEventMonitor.addKeyListener;
```

OS: ubuntu 12.04,
Java:

```
[ivan@noutbook ~/projects/Java/sch3dedit]$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All classes in packages named sun.* or com.sun.* are proprietary to the Sun / Oracle jdk and hence not part of OpenJDK. You should not use these classes as they are not part of the public API!